# Not getting expected output while using Countdownlatch and Executor in java

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am very new to Java **Multithreading** . Trying to learn countdownlatch and executor in Java threading and implemented the following code-

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ExecutorBasicFramework {


    class MyThread extends Thread{

        int iCount ; String name;
        CountDownLatch latch;

        public MyThread(int iCount, String name, CountDownLatch latch) {
            super();
            this.iCount = iCount;
            this.name = name;
            this.latch = latch;         
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                System.out.println(name+" Printing .... "+ ++iCount+" L "+latch.getCount());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }
            latch.countDown();

        }

    }

    public ExecutorBasicFramework() {
        createThread();
    }


    private void createThread() {
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(10);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){          
            MyThread thread = new MyThread(i*10, ""+i,latch);
            exec.execute(thread);

            try {
                latch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        exec.shutdownNow();     

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ExecutorBasicFramework();
    }

}
```

The output coming is as -

```
0 Printing .... 1 L 10
0 Printing .... 2 L 10
0 Printing .... 3 L 10
0 Printing .... 4 L 10
0 Printing .... 5 L 10
0 Printing .... 6 L 10
0 Printing .... 7 L 10
0 Printing .... 8 L 10
0 Printing .... 9 L 10
0 Printing .... 10 L 10
```

and then the flow is like keep on waiting.
My expected output is like above but after printing 0 , it should print similar output for 1 till 9 and then the program should be stopped.

I think the countdownlatch is waiting and waiting and its not going to increment the next counter of executor. So I am unable to get the expected output.
I am expecting output like -

```
0 Printing .... 1 L 10
0 Printing .... 2 L 10
0 Printing .... 3 L 10
0 Printing .... 4 L 10
0 Printing .... 5 L 10
0 Printing .... 6 L 10
0 Printing .... 7 L 10
0 Printing .... 8 L 10
0 Printing .... 9 L 10
0 Printing .... 10 L 10


1 Printing .... 11 L 9
1 Printing .... 12 L 9
1 Printing .... 13 L 9
1 Printing .... 14 L 9
1 Printing .... 15 L 9
1 Printing .... 16 L 9
1 Printing .... 17 L 9
1 Printing .... 18 L 9
1 Printing .... 19 L 9
1 Printing .... 20 L 9

and So on ... 
2 Printing .... 21 L 8
2 Printing .... 22 L 8
2 Printing .... 23 L 8
```

> with each decrement counter of latch , the next thread is pool must
>   execute a count till 10. and then again it must decrease the latch
>   counter and again the process repeats till the Thread 9 completes the
>   same

Please suggest some input .

Comment: Are you trying to wait for all of the jobs to finish?  What's the goal here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is to use the `CountDownLatch` to have the `main()` method wait until all threads have executed, then you should move the `latch.await()` *outside* the loop that submits the threads.
Also, you should not eat the `InterruptedException` without setting the interrupted flag again. ([see this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html)).

The correction would look like this :

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){          
    MyThread thread = new MyThread(i*10, ""+i,latch);
    exec.execute(thread);
}
try {
    latch.await();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

While this will certainly work, the Latch is suboptimal way to wait for the execution of a Runnable on another thread, when using an `ExecutorService`. If you use `submit()` rather than `execute()` you can use the `Future` returned by `submit()` to wait for the completion of the submitted `Runnable` by calling `get()` on it.

Answer (score 3):

So you are configuring a count down value of 10 `new CountDownLatch(10)` but your code is only decrementing it once per thread.  After you fork just 1 thread, you then wait for the latch but it is sitting at 9.

```
MyThread thread = new MyThread(i*10, ""+i,latch);
exec.execute(thread);
latch.await();
```

Not sure what you intended but maybe the `latch.countDown();` should be *inside* the for loop in the thread?

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
   ...
   // if you want the latch to count-down 10 times, it should be inside the loop
   latch.countDown();
}
// it should not go here, outside the loop
```

If the goal is to wait for all of the jobs to finish, you can do that with the `ExecutorService.awaitTermination(...)` method:

```
// submit jobs in loop
exec.shutdown();
exec.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Also, you should *not* be extending `Thread` in your `MyThread` class.  You should be implementing `Runnable`.  The only reason why your code works is that `Thread` also implements `Runnable` but `MyThread` should *not* be a `Thread`.  The `ExecutorService` takes a `Runnable` or a `Callable`, not a `Thread`.  It manages the threads for you internally to the service.

Comment: @Gray must have said this a million times here :)

Comment: No way @RalfH.  100k tops!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for inputs.
I found one more easy solution to get what I expected.
I just used `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();`as it already ensures that all tasks will be  guaranteed to be implemented sequentially.